# Javascripts don't work after calling changePage()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

Javascript doesn't work after calling changePage() in my example. Everything is fine after first request page, but when I try to select other items, changePage() doesn't work. 'pageshow' event didn't help me. What's wrong with me?

My simple example:

```
@model TestMobileSearch.Models.ListModelView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script>
    $(document).delegate("#main", "pageinit", function () {
        $("#filterCategory").bind('change', function () {
            $.mobile.changePage(this.value);
        });
    });

</script>

Category Name: @Model.CurrentName


<select id="filterCategory" data-theme="c" data-corners="false">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Names)
    {
        <option value="@Url.Action("List", "Cat", new {name = item})">@item</option>
    }
</select>
```

I use jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js

Thanks

Comment: my guess is that your javascript is not inside <div> that is the page itself

Comment: I tried to move script to <div data-role="page" id="main"> and to js file and include in page, but it didn't help.

Comment: put your js script not inside id="main" but to div data-role=page on the page you are going to, that is how my app works and I have multiple pages

Comment: I have only one page id="main", Is it your idea?   <div data-role="page" id="main">
           <script>
               $(document).delegate("#main", "pageinit", function () {
                   alert('pageinit');
                   $("#filterCategory").bind('change', function () {
                       $.mobile.changePage(this.value);
                   });
               });
           </script> ......

Comment: dont use delegate use .on(), dont use bind use .on(), that is depricated with new jquery, also put you javascript after your html code not before

Comment: Could you show me example? I tried to move script to <head> and to change delegate and bind. But still nothing. $(document).on('pageinit', '#main', function () {
            $("#filterCategory").on('change', function () {
                $.mobile.changePage(this.value);
            });
        });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33181/discussion-between-abdu-and-ukraine)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you delegate directly the #filtercategory change event?

```
$(document).delegate("#filterCategory", "change", function () {
  $.mobile.changePage(this.value);
});
```

By the way, `delegate` is deprecated. If you use a newer jQuery, use `on` instead.